# Try adding explicit like 'dynamic' or enable. implicit dynamic in your analysis option file

Tags: flutter, dart, swagger

[image]

I have tried

1. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31013
2. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27624
3. https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems

this is Swagger generated code block

```
Iterable<QueryParam> _convertParametersForCollectionFormat(
  String collectionFormat, String name, List value) {
  var params = <QueryParam>[];

  // preconditions
  if (name == null || name.isEmpty || value == null) return params;

  if (value is! List) {
    params.add(new QueryParam(name, parameterToString(value)));
    return params;
  }

  List values = value as List;

  // get the collection format
  collectionFormat = (collectionFormat == null || collectionFormat.isEmpty)
                     ? "csv"
                     : collectionFormat; // default: csv

  if (collectionFormat == "multi") {
    return values.map((v) => new QueryParam(name, parameterToString(v)));
  }

  String delimiter = _delimiters[collectionFormat] ?? ",";

  params.add(new QueryParam(name, values.map((v) => parameterToString(v)).join(delimiter)));
  return params;
}
```

could find what is the wrong I have done

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the type of the `value` parameter is `List` (aka. `List<dynamic>`), so at function entry, we know for sure that `value` is either a `List` or `null`.

Then the function returns if `value` is `null`.

The check after that, `if (value is! List) ...`, is completely unnecessary, because at this point `value` definitely *is* a `List`.

I'm guessing the original type of `value` was `dynamic` or `Object`, but it was changed to `List` at some point, while retaining the code that handled the non-`List` case.

The actual issue here is that the `values.map((v) => ...)` code infers `dynamic` for the `v` argument and you have enabled the "no implicit dynamic" lint. 
There is nothing wrong with your code as Dart code, but you are triggering a lint which disallows code inferring `dynamic` as a type for the `v` function parameter.
To fix that, you have to change the inference or disable the lint.

You can either:
* Disable that lint [globally](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file).
* Disable that lint [locally](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) by writing `// ignore: no_implicit_dynamic` on the line above.
* Write an explicit `dynamic`: `values.map((dynamic v) => ...).join(...)`.
* Don't write a closure at all: `values.map(parameterToString).join(...)` (this is recommended by the style guide too).